# Total Cumulated Number of Processed Rows in Spark Structured Streaming Query?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Is it possible to have the metric of Total Cumulated Number of Processed Rows in a Spark Structured Streaming Query since its start ?

I know from the [StreamingQueryListener Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryListener) that it is doable on a per batch basis, but what about total cumulated batches, does one need to keep track and compute it ? (*Really ?*)